# Importar e Exportar funções e classes em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, módulo-ecmascript, export

Quando tento importar uma classe mo console do navegador, o seguinte erro é apresentado:

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> ```

Arquivo `models/Evento.js`:

```
export class Evento {
    constructor(descricao, horaInicio, horaTermino){
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
        this.horaTermino = horaTermino;
    }
}
```

Arquivo `view/eventos.js`:

```
import {Evento} from '../model/Evento';
function criarObjetoEvento(){
    let id = localStorage.length + 1;
    const descricao = document.getElementById("descricao").value;
    const horaInicio = document.getElementById("horaInicio").value;
    const horaTermino = document.getElementById("horaTermino").value;
    const e = new Evento(descricao, horaInicio, horaTermino);
    console.log(e);
    criarEvento(e);
}
```

É possível realizar `import` e `export` dessa forma para arquivos que serão rodado no navegador? Ou existe outra forma de realizar modulação?

Comment: No HTML, como é que você faz a importação do módulo?

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar as declarações `import` e `export`, é necessário que você declare que o seu script é do tipo `module`. Exemplo:
html -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Teste</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./script.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="./api.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Nesse exemplo eu criei dois arquivos JS onde o `api.js` exporta uma variável para o `script.js`.

Também tem este link do [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) que fala sobre esse assunto.